# Image scaling size dependent on browser size

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using this site as an example : http://www.reebok.com/en-GB/

The header div height adjusts dependent on the size of the browser, and the inner content has 100% height & width.

Is this controlled by javascript of can this be done solely with CSS?

Answer (score 4):

You can only do this with the help of html & css. Write like this:

```
img{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/e8V47/

Comment: ... only in case if a parent item has fixed (defined) `width`.

Answer (score 1):

In your page, it's actually Javascript which is used.

The height of the container is modified inline (the `style` attribute)

```
<div class="module module-hero use-full-width displayed" data-module="Hero" style="height: 232px;">
```

It's however possible to do a similar thing with CSS, using `%` in height. For example :

```
.module{
   height:40%;        // A percentage relative to the parent element
}
```

Comment: If you look at the Reebok example, if the browser is scalled down to a smaller size the image is getting cropped to suit the size instead of resizing the full image. This is more what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

the image in your example is adjusting by browser, it's in , if you only set up the width or height, the browser will adjusts another automatically.